# Effect on WCF service with maximum value configurations

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, scalability, wcf-security

I am writing the WCF service that is supposed to have lots of traffic and load.
What is the main disadvantage service has if most of the values in configurations are set to maximum.

**For Example**, if i increase the OpenTimeout from 1 minute to 60 minutes.
Similarly if i increase the maxBufferSize, maxReceivedMessageSize to maximum.

I want to know how this can impact the scalability and performance of an application.
Because with maximum values i resolve my potential bugs/issues but i don't know its disadvantage

Comment: This bound on message size is intended to limit exposure to DoS-style attacks.

Comment: Yes, My Services are private and they are not much vulnerable to dos attack as they are hosted in cloud which provides itself some security. Is this the only thing we are controlling via configurations

Comment: I recommend setting these values according to your needs.